# Azure DevOps Multi Repo Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines, continuous-delivery

I am working with 9 multiple repositories with their own separate azure pipelines. However, during the deployment stage, there are some jobs/steps that are dependent on the status of a job from a separate deployment pipeline. If the resource (e.g A Resource Group) was not yet deployed, naturally the job/step dependent on it would fail. I cannot simply use `dependsOn` because it is from another pipeline.

Questions:

1. Is there a way for me to check, monitor, or wait (with a specified period of time) for a particular resource to be deployed?
2. Are these pipelines in need of restructuring?

I've seen documentation for the Multi-Repo pipeline. However, each pipeline must be deployable on its own and not waiting for another pipeline to finish.

Comment: Classic or YAML pipeline?

Comment: @TomaszKaniewski I am using YAML based pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

If you use YAML based pipeline you may consider [pipeline triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). It will allow you to trigger one pipeline after another. You may also apply [stages filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-172-update#stages-filters-for-pipeline-resource-triggers)

> In this sprint, we added support for 'stages' as a filter for pipeline resources in YAML. With this filter, you don't need to wait for the entire CI pipeline to be completed to trigger your CD pipeline. You can now choose to trigger your CD pipeline upon completion of a specific stage in your CI pipeline.